# jenkins, generate .jar for a project with jenkins

Tags: java, maven, github, jenkins, jar

I m a beginner in Jenkins, I just finished to install it with apache Ant and Maven.
Can anyone help me to generate .jar for a java project in gitHub

Comment: The steps vary between Ant and Maven. Which is your project using? If possible, please provide the GitHub link in your question.

Comment: Did I manage to answer your question?

Comment: I mean, did my answer below answer the question posed here? If so, then please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From Ant, you can simply add a jar task into your build.xml, for example...

```
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/YourApplication.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="path.to.your.main.Class"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

...and schedule that from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your ant targets from Jenkins. The process to generate jar isn't different. You can use an existing build*xml file to generate your jar file. You can schedule this as a job on Jenkins. I hope this helps!